# Product of subgroups and quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A \triangleleft G$ and $B \leq G$.
a) Show that $AB= \{ab: a\in A, b\in B\}$ is a subgroup.
b) Is $AB$ a normal subgroup of $G$? Give a proof or a counterexample.
c) Are the quotient groups $AB/B$ and $B/(A\cap B)$ isomorphic? Give a proof or a a counterexample.

---

I've done a) by straightforward computation but I'm struggling with b) and c). In b) I suspect the answer is "no" but I don't see the counterexample. In c) I expect the *first isomorphism theorem* to pop-up somehow but again couldn't find the proof. Could you give me a hint or solution to b) and c)?

Comment: For b) let $G$ be any group with a non-normal subgroup $B$ and take $A$ to be the trivial subgroup. This also happens to be a counterexample to c).